# Problem with setup multi-node cluster hadoop on windows

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to set up a multi-node Hadoop cluster between 2 windows devices. I am using Hadoop 3.3.1. how can I achieve that, please

(note: I was able to successfully create in Single-Node)

of course, I did these steps :

My network will be as follows:

```
master-IP   :  192.168.81.144
slave-IP    :  192.168.81.145
```

1. add below lines in Master-mode and SlaveNode  C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

```
192.168.81.144  hadoopMaster
192.168.81.145  hadoopSlave
```

in master, ping salve-IP worked

in slave, ping master-IP worked

2. add below lines in the workers file

```
hadoopMaster
hadoopSlave
```

3)format the HDFS file system

```
hdfs namenode -format
```

4. run below script on master node

```
start-dfs
```

but the slave node not working

Comment: Can you post the error message from Start-dfs or the hadoop error log?

Comment: I did not get any error, Start-dfs worked fine, but only the master worked and the slave did not work.

Comment: Look in the hadoop logs directory.  It will have information about what happened.  Post that and you'll get some help.